# Matlab Map Values from One Column to Values in Map

Tags: matlab, dictionary

In MATLAB R2016a, I am reading a table and creating a map from its two columns, Fruit (TEXT) and Calories (NUMBER):

```
map_table = readtable('map.csv');
Keys = table2cell(map_table(:, 1)); %Fruits
Values = table2cell(map_table(:, 2)); %Calories
Map = containers.Map(Keys, Values);
```

I also have another table with a column called Food (TEXT) containing all of the values of the Fruit column multiple times:

```
table = readtable('table.csv');
```

I want to create another column in table with the calories for every food in table.Food. This is accomplished by mapping the values in table.Food to the calories using Map.

I have tried the below but get an error:

```
Map(table.Food)

Error using containers.Map/subsref 
Specified key type does not match the type expected for this container.
```

When I pass a single key in the map it does return a number:

```
Map('Apple')
ans = 90
```

How can I accomplish the mapping? I know in **R**, there is a function called mapvalues which accomplishes this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass Map a cell array, so try a loop or using cellfun:

```
cellfun(@(x) M(x), table.Food)
```

Comment: I tried avoiding loops since I expected Matlab to handle a vectorized data structure. I used cellfun(@(x) Map(x), table.Food) to create the column I wanted.